# placing google maps in colorbox frame

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, colorbox

I am have just started with web developing.

I wanted to make googlemaps (specyfic search place, like [THIS](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=tower%20of%20london&hl=pl&ll=51.508101,-0.075359&spn=0.086543,0.11467&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=55.674612,58.710937&t=h&hq=tower%20of%20london&radius=15000&z=13&iwloc=A)) display in a colorbox popup.
I have gone thru every Q from stackoverflow about it but none of them seems to be working.
I wanted to have my link with image and after i click on it colorbox frame with map would show.

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: you mean you want to get infowindow background as with different color

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1290

Comment: I wanted to get result as here: [LINK](http://www.pallaschania.gr/home?lang=ENG) at the bottom when you click on restaurants location. In other words I wanted to make a link that when is clicked the colorbox frame appears with g map in it pointing location that I set.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I have found out what I did wrong.
The answer is: I included file calles: "js/jquery.colorbox-min.js.min.js", with doubled **'min.js'** at the end... and of course I had to include "js/jquery.colorbox-min.js".

Anyways thanks for fast respond.